# Scala PlayFramework: Merge two Seq's of different Models and create a JSON write

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm looking for an elegant way to create an JSON from the following scenario:

Assuming I have two case classes as models

```
case class PersonModel(id: Int, name: String)
case class CarModel(id: Int, model: CarModel)
```

After querying my database I retrieve a Seq[PersonModel] and Seq[CarModel]. I want to write both sequences into a single JSON Array of the following Structure:

```
[{Person1}, {Car1}, {Person2}, {Person3}, {Car3}]
```

So sorting all elements by their id and then writing them into a single array is what I want to do. How do experienced scala/play users go about it?

My Solution is a bit clumsy, as I lose type information. First I convert the *Cars* to *Persons*.

```
implicit def convert cars2Persons(car: CarModel) = 
  PersonModel(id = car.id, name = car.model)
```

Afterwards I do String checks on my `Writes[Person]`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot better to write out your sorted list of `Persons` using a `Writes[Person]` and likewise with your `Cars` and then concatenate them if you want them in the same Json object? This keeps your models (and the Reads/Writes that may deal with them) decoupled. Are you sending this back in a response, and if so is it a client-side requirement? If so, I would challenge the client-side. It's not good to convert your `Cars` to `Persons`.

Comment: Converting `Cars` to `Persons` definitely is bad. That is the main reason for my question, but I also want a single array of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a classic use case for existential types.

You can provide an existential type parameter as `T forSome {type T}`

```
import scala.language.existentials
import play.libs.json._

case class Person(id: Int, name: String)
case class Car(id: Int, model: String)

implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]
implicit val carFormat = Json.format[Car]

val listOfCars = List(
  Car(id = 1, model = "Tardis"),
  Car(id = 2, model = "Tardis"),
  Car(id = 3, model = "Tardis"),
  Car(id = 4, model = "Tardis")
)

val listOfPersons = List(
  Person(id = 1, name = "The Doctor"),
  Person(id = 2, name = "The New Doctor"),
  Person(id = 3, name = "The All New Doctor")
)

val list = List.empty[T forSome {type T}] ++ listOfPersons ++ listOfCars

val sortedList = list.sortBy({
  case Person(id, name) => id
  case Car(id, model) => id
})

val json = Json.toJson(sortedList)

val jsonString = Json.stringify(json)
```

Comment: thanks. This certainly worked, me and my team decided to create a third model and convert to that with a third property describing whether it is a Car or a Person. An now I know a bit more about scala's  *existential type* feature.